# C# every time button is clicked use a different text box or an alternative

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to achieve is every time you click a button it gets a value from the web browser and put it into a text box. I know how to do this for 2 presses but I want to be able to do up to 20.

Using the if statements this is what I have:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Token1.Text))
{
    Token1.Text = CaptchaWeb.Document.GetElementById("gcaptcha").GetAttribute("value");
}
else
{
    Token2.Text = CaptchaWeb.Document.GetElementById("gcaptcha").GetAttribute("value");
}
```

Now I want to make it so when both text box 1 and 2 have text use text box 3 and so on or just make it so the first time the button is pressed use text box 1 then next time use text box 2.

All tokens are unique so the current text boxes can't be overwritten. The 20 different codes have to be stored in separate text boxes.

Comment: is the random code you get guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Assuming that Token1 and Token2 are text boxes, I would instead use List<TextBox> TokenList and each button press adds a new textbox to the list,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

A- List all the controls

B- Select the controls that are of type TextBox, from the previous List (A)

C- Pick the First empty textbox (if any), from the previous List (B)

D- Write your Token Text over that TextBox (C)

```
var listOfAllControls = Controls.Cast<Control>();
var listOfTextBoxes= listOfAllControls.Where(control =>control.GetType()==typeof(TextBox));
TextBox emptyTextBox = (TextBox)listOfTextBoxes.FirstOrDefault(textbox => String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text));
if (emptyTextBox != null)
emptyTextBox.Text = CaptchaWeb.Document.GetElementById("gcaptcha").GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Thanks that works. My only problem is that it only works outside a tab control. How could I make that work in my tab control?

Comment: TabPage page = aTabControl.SelectedTab;
var listOfAllControls =  page.Controls.Cast<Control>();

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of 20 string and a counter to know where to add the new element in your array. Since you keep all your values in your array you can then just do something like  :

```
myArry[counter] = GaptchaWeb.Document.GetElementById("gcaptcha").GetAttribute("value");
counter++;
Token0.Text = myArry[0];
Token1.Text = myArray[1];
...
TokenX.Text = myArray[X];
```

hope that helps